# Making a Matlab program run with Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I have recently found a Matlab program (`TraitLab`) that I would like to try and use, but I do not have a Matlab license. Given that I thought GNU Octave and Matlab are mostly compatible, I tried to run it in octave, but the GUI way to run the program depends on loading a `.fig` file (now I know that I can use `load` to get the struct content of that file, but that does not make it a figure I can pass around to various GUI functions), and the headless way to run it reports many parse errors about

```
  nested functions not implemented in this context
```

Is there an obvious way to get a function written for Matlab that shows these two symptoms to run under Octave?

Comment: The obvious way is to rewrite it so it's valid Octave syntax. There is no magic MATLAB->Octave button, while they share much of the same syntax they are not completely compatible with each other.

Comment: Which version of Octave are you using? Octave supports Nested functions from version 3.8 if it has scoping rules compatible with Matlab. However the message is saying "in this context", so it might be special cases where nested functions are still not available. Just make sure you are running the latest Octave version.

Comment: My Octave is 4.0.3, the most recent one on Arch today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have downloaded TraitLab and it is obvious to me that it is a program that will need heavy modification for you to run on octave, which you probably don't have time (or possibly expert knowledge) to implement.

In this case you really only have two other options.

1) Write to the developers and ask them if they could re-implement their code in such a way to make it Octave compatible. I wouldn't hold my breath since it's an academic library, but it's always worth pointing out that there is demand for Octave compatible code. Also given this is old code, it's still worth contacting the stats lab in oxford, since they may have moved to a different codebase that might also suit your needs (e.g. I know that a lot of stats people in oxford have made the switch to julia).

2) In the meantime, if you really want to run this but you don't have matlab, find a matlab installation (e.g. from a friend, or at your university) and create a standalone-version using Matlab's "Application Compiler".
*OR*
Consider buying matlab. It has a reputation for being prohibitively expensive, partly because University-wide licences do cost an arm and a leg. But for personal use (especially if you  are a student?), with the right licence and only the necessary toolkits, it's actually not as prohibitively expensive as you might think.

Comment: PS. You could also actually ask the stats department if they could provide the "standalone" version themselves along their other downloads. I see no reason why they wouldn't (other than they might not care enough to click that particular button :p ).